# Override toString() Javascript On a Single Array Object

Tags: javascript, overloading, jslint

I have the following:

```
var version = [0,3,0];

// Override the version toString method.
version.__proto__.toString = function() {
    return this.join('.');
};
```

Which does the following

```
version.toString => '0.3.0'
```

JSlint moans that `__proto__` is a reserved name - which is correct.

I assume I am overloading incorrectly.

I do not want to

```
Array.prototype.toString
```

as that'll override all arrays to replace , with .?

Comment: `[].__proto__.toString === Array.prototype.toString`.

Comment: @katspaugh - The attribute '\_\_proto\_\_' is unchangeable, but 'prototype' is. In some cases your comparison does not always have to be true. Some JavaScript actively use this behavior (e.g. ExtJS)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just set the method on the array directly:

```
var version = [0,3,0];

// Override the version toString method.
version.toString = function() {
    return this.join('.');
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  Making it way to complicated for myself!