# Override toString() of a property of a class - javascript

Tags: javascript, class, overriding, tostring

I'm trying to (re)learn OOP in javascript. I'd like to override the `toString` method of an array that is a property of my object/class.
[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901754/override-tostring-javascript-on-a-single-array-object) works for simple arrays, but not as I'd like for the one in my object/class.
I got it working with `__proto__` but it seems to be deprecated. I'd like to not override the `Array.toString`, only the `Solver.foo.toString`. I'm probably missing something obvious. Thanks.

```js
//solution that works on simple array
let version = [0, 3, 0];

version.toString = function() {
  return this.join('foo');
};

console.log("simple array: " + version);

//Same solution for my object/class
class Solver {
  constructor(arr) {
    this.foo = arr;
    this.foo.toString = function() {
      return this.join('foo');
    };
  };
}

//that works here
let bar = new Solver([0, 3, 0]);
console.log("property array: " + bar.foo);
//but not here
bar.foo = [0, 3, 0];
console.log("property array: " + bar.foo);
```

Comment: The second console log is not working as expected because you've overridden `bar.foo` with a fresh new array that does not have the `toString` mutation. What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want the mutation to stay even after you update the value for `foo`?

Comment: There is no obvious solution to this indeed, but do you understand the problem (why it no longer works after you assign a new array to `bar.foo`)?

Comment: What if you have two such classes, and one joins the string with "foo", and the other with "baz". Then you create an instance of both; `bar1` and `bar2`. Then you do `bar2.foo = bar1.foo`. What should happen? Should that assignment have an impact on the result of `bar1.foo.toString()`? Think about it... What is the reason why you want this in the first place?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Yep, this is exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: @Bergi My guessing was the exact comment of Ghassen. Thanks for the comment though (I was especially scared of missing something obvious).

Comment: @trincot In your example, bar2.foo.toString should happen. No matter what is assigned, I wanted to know if we could override ("once") the `toString` method of the `foo` property of `bar2`. I just want to learn more about the subtility of javascript. In a personnal project, I have a class that contains an array. And at solme point, I display it as a string (with some checks). Instead of having a `displayAsString`method, I just wanted to know if we could override the existing `toString()`.

Comment: @CronosS You should however make a `toString` method for your class, not overwrite the `toString` method of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you make use of [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) for JavaScript classes. With a setter, a simple assignment becomes a call to a internal method of the class, you can leverage this to always make sure you mutate the value to have the updated `toString` function. A getter will help you call on the value from the outside.

Here is a working example:

```js
class Solver {
    constructor(arr) {
        this.foo = arr;
    };
    
    set foo(arr) {
        this.fooValue = arr.slice(); // copying to avoid mutating the outside array
        this.fooValue.toString = function() {
            return this.join('foo');
        };
    }
    
    get foo() {
        return this.fooValue;
    }
}

let bar = new Solver([0, 3, 0]);
console.log("constructor property array: " + bar.foo);
const outsideArray = [0, 3, 1];
console.log("outside property array: " + outsideArray);
bar.foo = outsideArray;
console.log("setter property array: " + bar.foo);
```

Comment: I'm already using getters and setters in my class. The thing is that the `toString` method is overriden at each assignement. I wanted to know if there was something more optimized (like altering the prototype of the property once). If not, it's still a good answer. Thanks!

Comment: Well the only other thing I can think of is to create a new type class called `MutatedArray` that inherits from the regular `Array` and mutates the `toString` method, but I would not recommend it because you'll have to always do `new MutatedArray([])`, so it's not any different from updating the regular `toString` everytime.

Comment: And this approach is fine because you don't have to worry about the transformation, it's taken care of for you internally in the class, also you don't have to corrupt all arrays from the outside like the `__proto__` is doing.